# SQL Server : Avoid updating columns when values do not change in merge

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to avoid updating the columns whose "new value" doesn't change in a merge statement?

I still need the update to happens since I need to retrieve fields from the inserted table in an output clause.

The goal would of course be to avoid IO writes

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET 
        productName = Src.productName -- Only if Src.productName <> productName
        , productNameModel = Src.productNameModel -- Only if Src.productNameModel <> productNameModel
        , brandID = Src.brandID -- Only if Src.brandID <> brandID
        , ean = Src.ean -- Only if Src.ean <> ean
        , categoryID = Src.categoryID -- Only if Src.categoryID <> categoryID
        , resellerPrijsEx = Src.resellerPrijsEx -- Only if Src.resellerPrijsEx <> resellerPrijsEx
        , inStock = Src.inStock -- Only if Src.inStock <> inStock
        , warrantyID = Src.warrantyID -- Only if Src.warrantyID <> warrantyID
        , productNamePn = Src.productNamePn -- Only if Src.productNamePn <> productNamePn
OUTPUT Src.ID, inserted.ID, Src.hasDescription INTO @tblID (tmpID, ID, hasDescription) -- Yet UPDATE is required since I need to retrieve inserted ID
;
```

Comment: If the two values are the same, what difference does it make?

Comment: It would cause a useless write (overwriting a value with the exact same value) on the disk, I think.

Comment: you're almost certainly over thinking this.

Comment: don't you wish someone could tell us there's indeed a way to do that and improve performance of your futures merge queries?

Comment: No. I really don't think it's going to make any difference whatsoever

Comment: Writing the extra info will be much quicker than performing a conditional check of every field.

Comment: You can use `WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS(SELECT dest.productName, dest.productNameModel EXCEPT SELECT Src.productName, Src.productNameModel)` (omitted other fields for brevity). The impact of this check will vary. [The Impact of Non-Updating Updates](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/11/the_2D00_impact_2D00_of_2D00_update_2D00_statements_2D00_that_2D00_don_2D00_t_2D00_change_2D00_data.aspx) has more about this.

Comment: @Serge - you think that, for each column, for each row of an update, SQL Server performs a separate write to *disk*?

Comment: @Damien, no but I though it writes less bit. Though after reading a few articles discussed here I don't know what to think expect "there are indeed some optimization when a column's value doesn't change".

Comment: I don't think about write operation cost but I want to know which fields really updated.

Answer (score 4):

I'm with Serge ! 
If a certain number (or all) source and target records match then I might want to avoid doing any unnecessary updates also !

I can see why people might think it doesn't matter .. and in some or lots of cases it doesn't matter if you replace a certain amount of data with exactly the same data, unless you are tracking audit type info with triggers or transaction logging with triggers, then it might matter !

Martin Smith's WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS(SELECT ... EXCEPT SELECT .. ) is a good comment and I tried using this. I wondered if this only avoid doing the updates when all records match but no .. it does just as I would wish ..  (I've got a bit of an extreme case on hand with a few 100 columns and ~250,000 rows). Please see a smaller code example below !

Another option might be to use SSIS and the slowly changing dimension component.

A good article is here:

http://www.made2mentor.com/2013/05/writing-t-sql-merge-statements-the-right-way/

A full scale code example, which uses code as per Martin Smith's comment to avoid doing unnecessary record updates, and handles null values, is this example:

```
CREATE TABLE Clinical.AAATargetTable (
    category_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    category_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    amount DECIMAL(10 , 2 )
);

INSERT INTO Clinical.AAATargetTable(category_id, category_name, amount)
VALUES(1,'Children Bicycles',15000),
    (2,'Comfort Bicycles',25000),
    (3,'Cruisers Bicycles',13000),
    (4,'Cyclocross Bicycles',10000);


CREATE TABLE Clinical.AAASourceTable (
    category_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    category_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    amount DECIMAL(10 , 2 )
);


INSERT INTO Clinical.AAASourceTable(category_id, category_name, amount)
VALUES(1,'Children Bicycles',15000),
    (3,'Cruisers Bicycles',13000),
    (4,'Cyclocross Bicycles',20000),
    (5,'Electric Bikes',10000),
    (6,'Mountain Bikes',10000);

MERGE Clinical.AAATargetTable t 
    USING Clinical.AAASourceTable s
ON (s.category_id = t.category_id)
WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS (SELECT s.category_id,s.category_name,s.amount EXCEPT SELECT t.category_id,t.category_name,t.amount )
    THEN UPDATE SET 
        t.category_name = s.category_name,
        t.amount = s.amount
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT (category_id, category_name, amount)
         VALUES (s.category_id, s.category_name, s.amount)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
    THEN DELETE;    


UPDATE Clinical.AAASourceTable set amount =1234 where category_id=1;


MERGE Clinical.AAATargetTable t 
    USING Clinical.AAASourceTable s
ON (s.category_id = t.category_id)
WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS (SELECT s.category_id,s.category_name,s.amount EXCEPT SELECT t.category_id,t.category_name,t.amount )
    THEN UPDATE SET 
        t.category_name = s.category_name,
        t.amount = s.amount
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT (category_id, category_name, amount)
         VALUES (s.category_id, s.category_name, s.amount)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
    THEN DELETE;    


DROP TABLE Clinical.AAATargetTable;
DROP TABLE Clinical.AAASourceTable;
```

Another comment is that if a MERGE is only doing an UPDATE then the MERGE can be rewritten as an UPDATE statement. An UPDATE statement will perform better than a MERGE.
The technique of detection of data changes as per above example can also be applied to UPDATE statements:
ie. .. in the WHERE clasue ...   AND EXISTS ( SELECT ... EXCEPT SELECT ...)

A larger non trivial example of this as part of an UPDATE statement is as per this (apologies for not giving a simple example here, will come back to this if time permits).

```
UPDATE dbo.ContractCampusVersions
    SET ICULevel = s.ICULevel,
           SecondTierCategory = s.SecondTierCategory
FROM                   
   ( 
   SELECT 
       I.ProviderNumber, 
          I.AgreementNumber,
          'Main' AS CampusID, 
          CCV.Version,                        
    PC.AHSACampusID AS ICULevel,
          PCR.Tier2Cat AS SecondTierCategory
   FROM
    dbo.ImportAHSAHospitalDetails I         
       JOIN dbo.ProviderCampuses PC ON (I.ProviderNumber = PC.ProviderID) and (PC.CampusID = 'Main')
       JOIN dbo.ProviderCampusRevisions PCR ON (PCR.ProviderID=I.ProviderNumber) AND (PCR.CampusID = 'Main') 
           AND PCR.EffDate = 
                     (
            SELECT MAX(EffDate)
            FROM dbo.ProviderCampusRevisions
            WHERE ProviderID = I.ProviderNumber
            AND CampusID = 'Main'
                     )
    JOIN dbo.ContractCampusVersions CCV on (I.AgreementNumber = CCV.AgreementID) and (I.ProviderNumber = CCV.ProviderID) and (CCV.CampusID = 'Main')
          and CCV.Version = (select max(Version)
                                  from dbo.ContractCampusVersions CCVM where CCVM.AgreementID = CCV.AgreementID and CCVM.ProviderID = CCV.ProviderID and CCVM.CampusID = 'Main' 
                               )

   WHERE 
       I.AgreementNumber IS NOT NULL
       AND I.ClosedDate IS NULL             
   ) s
   WHERE (s.AgreementNumber = ContractCampusVersions.AgreementID) AND (s.ProviderNumber = ContractCampusVersions.ProviderID) AND (ContractCampusVersions.CampusID = 'Main') AND (ContractCampusVersions.Version = s.Version)
   AND EXISTS
       (
       SELECT    
        s.ICULevel,
        s.SecondTierCategory                
   EXCEPT
          SELECT
        ContractCampusVersions.ICULevel,
        ContractCampusVersions.SecondTierCategory                  
    )
;
```

Comment: I use this select except select difference detection because it does handle nulls ..

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it really matters if you skip a few fields and not update them. SQL Server doesn't make a separate I/O operation for updating each field and its I/O operations are highly optimized so skipping a few fields won't make a difference (if one record fits into one page, at least).

Check a bit more about how SQL Server writes pages to disk, e.g. here: [Writing Pages](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337560%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). You will see that in practice skipping fields won't make a difference to performance but will complicate your code.